# Android: JSON data loaded into adapter

Tags: android

This might be a simple Java issue I'm struggling with but I'm looking to the community to assist me here as I have hit a brick wall with this situation.

I successfully have data coming in off of a MySQL database and brought to the application through JSON. During parsing I was trying to create another array to be passed onto an ArrayAdapter to be used in a ListView. Here is the code I'm having an issue with:

```
 try{

       jArray = new JSONArray(result);
       JSONObject json_data=null;

           for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
              json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
              ct_id=json_data.getString("ID");
              ct_name=json_data.getString("Player2N");

              Games game_data[] = new Games[]
              {
                new Games(ct_id, ct_name)     
              };

           }

           GameAdapter adapter = new GameAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_item_row, game_data);

           listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

           View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_header_row, null);
           listView1.addHeaderView(header);
           listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
 }
```

This line: `GameAdapter adapter = new GameAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_item_row, game_data);`

More specifically the game_data is highlighted red in Eclipse. Where I am curious is why does game_data get out of reach after end of loop? I'm just trying to add specific fields within the row from JSON to the adapter here.

I also tried going through the loop within setting up the array but still no dice as new Games[] gets an error. Here is an example:

```
   Games game_data[] = new Games[]
                       {
                        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                         json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                         ct_id=json_data.getString("ID");
                          ct_name=json_data.getString("Player2N");

//                  Games game_data[] = new Games[]
  //                {
                    new Games(ct_id, ct_name);    
    //              };

               }
```

**error: Variable must either provide dimension expressions or array initializer.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps...

```
try{

   jArray = new JSONArray(result);
   JSONObject json_data=null;
   Games game_data[];
   game_data[] = new Games[jArray.length()];
       for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
          json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
          ct_id=json_data.getString("ID");
          ct_name=json_data.getString("Player2N");

          game_data[i] = new Games(ct_id, ct_name);


       }

       GameAdapter adapter = new GameAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_item_row, game_data);

       listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

       View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_header_row, null);
       listView1.addHeaderView(header);
       listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

}

Comment: Umesh, this works perfectly (with minor adjustment) I just removed the:
    Games game_data[];

Then I added Games to the front of the next line. Thank you kindly sir!

Comment: Hi Dustin, Glad i could help you. If you feel that this answer has helped you, consider marking it answered so that other users can find the solution easily. Its a tick mark on the left hand side of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking that Games is your POJO class so you can better do something like this,

Create a List of the POJO class

```
private List<Games> games= new ArrayList<Games>();
```

Now you can add your content in the games list.

```
              for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                  json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                  ct_id=json_data.getString("ID");
                  ct_name=json_data.getString("Player2N");
                  games.add(new Games(ct_id, ct_name));
              }
```

And finally pass the list in the Adapter.

```
GameAdapter adapter = new GameAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_item_row, games);
```

Comment: Lalit, thank you for this as it helped me figure something else out that I was working on.

Comment: Also you should check mark the answer that finally worked for you, so that future user can get benefit from this answer.

Answer (score 0):

**error: Variable must either provide dimension expressions or array initializer.**

=> This error is obvious because you haven't define any dimensions value to create an array and also haven't passed any initialization to this array.

So I think you are doing wrong, instead do it like:

```
Games game_data[] = new Games(ct_id, ct_name);
```

This is the correct way to call a constructor.

And i don't know what you have written inside the Games class so i just have mentioned about the calling of constructor.

Comment: Paresh, I was still struggling with using this one but I found the simple solution so I appreciate your help!